# Why aren't traits Sized by default?

Tags: rust, traits, language-design

I defined a trait `ReadTag` which contains a function that returns `Self` but such yields an error:

```rust
trait ReadTag {
    fn read_out(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> Option<Self>;
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:2:37
  |
2 |     fn read_out(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> Option<Self>;
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

The error is fixed by adding `Sized` as a supertrait, which makes sense, but why isn't `Sized` the default like it is for functions?

```rust
fn my_sized<T>(t: T) { } // all good, Sized is opt-out :)

fn my_unsized<T: ?Sized>(t: T) { } // not allowed
```

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is that functions _need_ sized parameters to place their arguments on the stack, whereas no such restriction exists for traits.

Comment: This question was discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426370/my-why-question-was-closed-for-being-opinion-based)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation on [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) covers why it is not a default/implicit bound on traits:

> A trait does not have an implicit `Sized` bound as this is incompatible with trait objects where, by definition, the trait needs to work with all possible implementors, and thus could be any size.
>
> Although Rust will let you bind `Sized` to a trait, you won’t be able to use it to form a trait object later:
>
> ```
> trait Foo { }
> trait Bar: Sized { }
>
> struct Impl;
> impl Foo for Impl { }
> impl Bar for Impl { }
>
> let x: &dyn Foo = &Impl;    // OK
> // let y: &dyn Bar = &Impl; // error: the trait `Bar` cannot
>                             // be made into an object
> ```

Disallowing `dyn Trait` by default does sound like a poor choice.

---

As for why `Sized` *is* the default on everything else (functions, structs, enums, types, etc,) requires more guesswork. Likely it is just more common to require `Sized` types in most other contexts and requiring `T: Sized` everywhere would be a noisy burden. The latter (of relaxing the constraint with `T: ?Sized` when unsized types *are* desired) is the least cumbersome of the two. Corroborated by [this answer](/a/57366189/2189130).